# Disconnecting the load from a synchronous generator

Tags: synchronous, electric-machine, alternator

How is the terminal voltage of a synchronous generator affected when we disconnect the load ?

Comment: It rises. What are you expecting? Improve your question.

Comment: Why does it rise? Here's my thoughts. We basically have an open circuit so the terminal voltage will be the one it was before plus the voltage drop that we had because of the synchronous reactance. Am I correct?

Comment: I think you should add your comment to your question.  I'd also tweak your title to reflect your actual question.